# Detecting defects on the preform

Tags: python, c++, opencv, computer-vision, pca

I'm doing a project to detect defects on the preform. In principle, I have everything ready, but my algorithm is quite poorly resistant to noise and other distortions, which puts its effectiveness in doubt. Can you tell me how I can improve it? Thank you in advance for your help :)
P.S. I write in C++, but I understand Python code pretty well, so you can use any language that suits you.

```
#include "widget.h"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Point cntr;

Mat main_part, fg, bg, preform, bin, M, rotated, ROI;

double getOrientation(const vector<Point> &pts)
{
    //Construct a buffer used by the pca analysis
    int sz = static_cast<int>(pts.size());
    Mat data_pts = Mat(sz, 2, CV_64F);
    for (int i = 0; i < data_pts.rows; i++)
    {
        data_pts.at<double>(i, 0) = pts[i].x;
        data_pts.at<double>(i, 1) = pts[i].y;
    }
    //Perform PCA analysis
    PCA pca_analysis(data_pts, Mat(), PCA::DATA_AS_ROW);
    //Store the center of the object
    cntr = Point(static_cast<int>(pca_analysis.mean.at<double>(0, 0)),
                 static_cast<int>(pca_analysis.mean.at<double>(0, 1)));
    //Store the eigenvalues and eigenvectors
    vector<Point2d> eigen_vecs(2);
    vector<double> eigen_val(2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        eigen_vecs[i] = Point2d(pca_analysis.eigenvectors.at<double>(i, 0),
                                pca_analysis.eigenvectors.at<double>(i, 1));
        eigen_val[i] = pca_analysis.eigenvalues.at<double>(i);
    }
    double angle = atan2(eigen_vecs[0].y, eigen_vecs[0].x); // orientation in radians
    return angle;
}

// Using for find preform
int max_contour_area(vector<vector<Point>> &v) {
    int max_area = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        if(v[max_area].size() < v[i].size())
            max_area = (int)i;
    }
    return max_area;
}

int main()
{
    fg = imread("C:\\Users\\Roman\\Pictures\\pf6.bmp", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE),
    bg = imread("C:\\Users\\Roman\\Pictures\\background.bmp", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    vector<vector<Point>> contours, correct_contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

    resize(fg, fg, Size(), 0.3, 0.3, INTER_AREA);
    resize(bg, bg, Size(), 0.3, 0.3, INTER_AREA);

    absdiff(fg, bg, preform);

    threshold(preform, bin, 10, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
    findContours(bin, contours, hierarchy, RETR_LIST, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    int max_area = max_contour_area(contours);
    RotatedRect rBox = minAreaRect(contours[max_area]);
    double angle_pca = getOrientation(contours[max_area]) * (180 / CV_PI);

    if(rBox.size.width < rBox.size.height) swap(rBox.size.height, rBox.size.width);

    M = getRotationMatrix2D(cntr, angle_pca, 1.0);
    // perform the affine transformation
    warpAffine(fg, rotated, M, fg.size(), INTER_CUBIC, BORDER_DEFAULT);
    // crop the resulting image
    getRectSubPix(rotated, rBox.size, cntr, ROI);

    if(ROI.cols < ROI.rows)
        rotate(ROI, ROI, ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE);

    threshold(ROI, bin, 250, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV);
    findContours(bin, contours, RETR_LIST, THRESH_BINARY_INV);

    max_area = max_contour_area(contours);

    Moments mnt = moments(contours[max_area]);
    Point center_mass(mnt.m10/mnt.m00, mnt.m01/mnt.m00);
    Point p1(contours[max_area][0].x, 0),
          p2(contours[max_area][0].x, ROI.rows-1);

    // Using for find rectangle into preform
    for(size_t i = 0; i < contours[max_area].size(); i++) {
        if(contours[max_area][i].y == 0)
            p1.x = p1.x < contours[max_area][i].x ? contours[max_area][i].x : p1.x;
        if(contours[max_area][i].y == ROI.rows-1)
            p2.x = p2.x < contours[max_area][i].x ? contours[max_area][i].x : p2.x;
    }

    if((p1.x & p2.x) > ROI.cols/2) {
        p1.x = ROI.cols * 0.79;
        p2.x = ROI.cols * 0.05;
    }
    else {
        p1.x = ROI.cols * 0.17;
        p2.x = ROI.cols * 0.91;
    }

    p1.y += ROI.rows * 0.2;
    p2.y -= ROI.rows * 0.2;

    Rect rect_main(p1, p2);
    main_part = ROI(rect_main);

    adaptiveThreshold(main_part, bin, 255, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, THRESH_BINARY_INV, 21, 3);

    findContours(bin, contours, hierarchy, RETR_LIST, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    // deleting too large or too small contours
    for(uint i = (uint)contours.size()-1; i != 0; --i) {
        double area = contourArea(contours[i]);
        if ((area >= 30) && (area <= 70))
            correct_contours.push_back(contours[i]);
    }

    Mat defect;

    main_part.convertTo(main_part, COLOR_GRAY2RGB);
    ROI.convertTo(ROI, COLOR_GRAY2RGB);

    // Drawing contours
    vector<vector<Point>> contours_poly( correct_contours.size() );
    for( size_t i = 0; i < correct_contours.size(); i++ )
        approxPolyDP( correct_contours[i], contours_poly[i], 1, true );    
    for( size_t i = 0; i< correct_contours.size(); i++ )
        drawContours( main_part, correct_contours, (int)i, Scalar(255, 0, 255) );

    imshow("ROI", ROI);
    imshow("main", main_part);

    if(waitKey() == 27) waitKey(0);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Source image:
[background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gqJ6.jpg) [pf1.bmp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dd0oo.jpg)

Result of program:
[preform central part threshold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8pgv.jpg) [preform result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ubkxc.jpg)

So, [that`s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHK3R.jpg) what I want to get

Comment: What are the defects ? What do you really need ?

Comment: What's the desired output? Your problem is a little bit unclear, please explain in more detail what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I added another image. The customer didn't give me the preforms with the defect, but said we could count these artifacts as them

Comment: I guess you are using an adaptive threshold to determine defect locations... but that's difficult because what you are looking for has different shapes and orientations ... etc I would locate using a threshold and use a classifier . or go with deep learning object detection for this task.

Comment: what do you mean by classifier?